# How to store a value from awk in a Python variable

Tags: python, linux, awk

I'm trying to store a result of random numbers from an awk command into a Python variable. I've used os.popen to make the command but it just gives me the same number all the time, which is 512 when I print it. 
This is the line `var = os.popen("awk 'BEGIN {print int(9*rand()) ' ' int(9*rand()) }'").read()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **CAUTION: In most awk implementations, including gawk, rand() starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk.44 Thus, a program generates the same results each time you run it. The numbers are random within one awk run but predictable from run to run. This is convenient for debugging, but if you want a program to do different things each time it is used, you must change the seed to a value that is different in each run. To do this, use srand().**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and info. I will be trying it.

Answer (score 2):

that's expected behavior unless you set the seed

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); ...'
```

on the other hand your approach of using `awk` for random value generation instead of Python is questionable...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes I know I should use Python random number system instead, it would been much easier. The problem is that this is for a project and the professor want a mix between Python, zenity and awk.